# How to solve the "^" is not valid at start of code block issue?

Tags: blazor

I am currently trying to intergrade the WebEx SDK to a Blazor project. I also quite new at this so bare with me a bit.
I followed the WebEx official guild to intergrade the browser SDK. in step 3, they instruct me to put the line below to the project.

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/webex@^1/umd/webex.min.js"></script>
```

so I do what they told me and the following error appeared.

```js
CS1525: invalid expression term ";"
RZ1005: "^" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, 
keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are vaild
RZ1005: Only identifies, keywords, comments, "(" and BlazorApp1, "{" are valid.
```

additional info: I created the project using the default blazor option, and added the ad formation line in the _host.cshtml page near the end of the body section. I made no modification except add this line.

how should I solve it?

I tried googling the solution before hand and nothing come of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the `@` :

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/webex@@^1/umd/webex.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, I added the @ in and the error is gone. however the other pages is still unable to detect the library. when I put the use the elements in the library, it just say "the type or namespace name could not be found".

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, what is exactly this line that you added but it looks it is syntax error. If your is a script, please warp your line with `@{myscript}`